# Is there a bidirectional map in matlab?

Tags: matlab, dictionary, bidirectional

Is there a bidirectional map data structure in matlab that is more efficient than using containers.Map's keys and values in an opposite direction? Also what is the most efficient way to use ordinary maps for this purpose?

Comment: What data do you want to store?

Comment: Mapping between integers

Comment: Please add example data to your question. Also tell us how often you are going to insert new data or delete data into your bidirectional map. Different solutions will show different efficiency for different use cases. For positive integers you could try [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html).

Comment: This is a general question and bidirectional maps are well known structures.

Comment: If you want the most general solution, you won't get the most efficient one for your use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `containers.Map` class does not natively support bidirectional mapping (as of R2014b). The methods supported are listed in `doc containers.Map`:

- `isKey`: Determine if `containers.Map` object contains key
- `keys`:  Identify keys of `containers.Map` object
- `length`:    Length of `containers.Map` object
- `remove`:    Remove key-value pairs from `containers.Map` object
- `size`:  Size of `containers.Map` object
- `values`:    Identify values in `containers.Map` object

---

You could either implement this functionality yourself, by building

```
inverse = containers.Map(original.values, original.keys)
```

---

Or use the [Map2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40323-map2-enhanced-map-class)-class provided by 
*Mikko Leppänen* on the File Exchange:

> [...] Also a bidirectional use of 
>           key-value pairs is supported (like Boost.Bimap library).

---

If your key-value pairs are positive integers and you rarely change the map, you could use `sparse`, which should be quite efficient.

```
map = sparse(keys, 1, values);
inverseMap = sparse(nonzeros(map), 1, find(map))
```

Comment: Does that mean that there is no built-in implementation?

Comment: @Vasei: No, there is no built-in bidirectional map. I added the additional information.